# Is it possible to get a RethinkDB document only knowing the UUID (no table)?

Tags: rethinkdb

If UUIDs are unique across RethinkDB, I was wondering whether you could get a document having only its UUID, without knowing the table it resides in.

I am thinking of something like:

```
r.db('test').get('[UUID]').run()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write `r.db('test').tableList().map(function(table){return r.table(table).get(UUID);})`.